# How to get promise attribute?

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and Angular and I struggle with working with an API.
I can get the promise, but the thing that I don't understand is :
How do you access attribute if you don't even know their name ?
console.logging doesn't help much as you can easly see the value in the promise but I can't find it's name.

Can someone explain me how to access a promise's data correctly ?

Comment: Can you please add some code to the question? So that we can have an idea about the problem

Comment: It was a general case, so a code sample showing me trying anything but the correct way wouldn't help much as I just wanted to know how to do it. Googling "get promise attribute values" didn't really help because their cases were specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a promise's data you need to call `.then` on it. Without a given code example I'm providing one for you:

```
const myPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => res({foo: 'bar'}));

myPromise.then((res) => {
  console.log(res); // Will be {foo: 'bar'}
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, mine looks like this (it's about checking products last update):
`var lastCheck;  this.getLastUpdate().then(res => lastCheck = res);`